# Exclude subdirectory from zip archive -- explain syntax please

Tags: wildcards, zip, syntax

I want to zip a folder recursively, but exclude certain directories (`temp/.hidden` in the example below). I want the zip file to have a top level folder which would be `temp` in the example below, hence my working directory is `temp`.

```
mkdir -p temp/subdir
touch temp/subdir/keepthisfile.txt
touch temp/excludethisfile.txt
mkdir temp/.hidden
touch temp/.hidden/exclude.txt
cd temp/
```

Code I have to achieve what I want is either

```
zip -r temp.zip ../temp/ -x ../temp/excludethisfile.txt ../temp/.hidden/* ../temp/.hidden/
```

Or more concisely (syntax gleaned from elsewhere online)

```
zip -r temp.zip ../temp/ -x ../temp/excludethisfile.txt ../temp/*.hidden*
```

I can see why this would work, but I can't see why the code below doesn't do the same thing (i.e. why do I need `../temp/*.hidden*` rather than just `../temp/.hidden*`?)

```
zip -r temp.zip ../temp/ -x ../temp/excludethisfile.txt ../temp/.hidden*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell expands `../temp/.hidden*` into `../temp/.hidden` before executing Zip; this pattern no longer matches `../temp/.hidden/exclude.txt`.  You should quote the pattern, as recommended by Zip manual page:

```
zip -r temp.zip ../temp/ -x ../temp/excludethisfile.txt '../temp/.hidden*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Having now properly RFTM, my man pages suggest

> The backslash avoids the shell filename substitution, so that the name matching is performed by  zip  at all directory levels.

So the code becomes
    zip -r temp.zip ../temp/ -x ../temp/exclude.txt ../temp/.hidden/\*

I prefer the quoting though :)